# AppleScript Move File(s) failing. What did I do wrong?

Tags: file, applescript, move

I'm working on my first AppleScript and have run into an error on the last command. Basically, the script is supposed to loop through all of the jpg's in a given folder ("/Volumes/Public2/Pictures/LINP/temp/") and move them all into sub-folders based on the date in the file name:

Ex. 000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg

Where 20130604 is the date (2013-06-04)

The part of my script that gets each of the file names and loops over them, creating the necessary sub-folders works great. No issues at all. It's when I try the actual "move" that I get a System Events error. So, to start, here's the complete script:

```
set workFolder to "/Volumes/Public2/Pictures/LINP/temp/"
log workFolder
set workFolder to (POSIX file workFolder) as alias
log workFolder


tell application "System Events"

    --get files to work on
    set filesToProcess to files of workFolder
    --log filesToProcess

    repeat with thisFile in filesToProcess

        log thisFile

        set {fileName, fileExt} to {name, name extension} of thisFile
        log fileName
        log fileExt

        if (fileExt is in "(*jpg*)" and ((length of fileName) is greater than 10)) then
            --get name of file without extension
            set rootName to text 1 thru -((length of fileExt) + 2) of fileName
            log rootName

            --break apart the file name to get to the imortant stuff
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "_"

            --store the camera name
            set cameraName to text item 1 of rootName
            log cameraName

            --store the full date
            set photoDate to text item 3 of rootName
            log photoDate

            --cut out the time information
            set photoDate to text 1 thru 8 of photoDate
            log photoDate

            --break out the year
            set photoYear to text 1 thru 4 of photoDate
            log photoYear

            --break out the month
            set photoMonth to text 5 thru 6 of photoDate
            log photoMonth

            --break out the day
            set photoDay to text 7 thru 8 of photoDate
            log photoDay

            --combine parts into a new name of the form "YYYY-MM-DD"
            set photoFolder to photoYear & "-" & photoMonth & "-" & photoDay
            log photoFolder

            --make sure a correctly named folder exists
            set targetFolder to my checkForFolder({parentFolder:(workFolder as text), folderName:photoFolder}) as text
            log "targetFolder: " & targetFolder
            log thisFile

            log "targetFolder Class: " & class of targetFolder
            log "thisFile Class: " & class of thisFile


            set finalTarget1 to (POSIX file targetFolder) as alias as string
            log "finalTarget1: " & finalTarget1
            log "finalTarget1 Class: " & class of finalTarget1

            --Here's where the error pops up. I've tried both HFS and POSIX formats for the target folder, but the issue seems to be with the file
            --Yes, the files definitely exist (I've confirmed this). I show exactly what the values are and error messages I'm getting at the end of this post
            move thisFile to the folder finalTarget1
            move thisFile to the folder targetFolder

        end if
    end repeat
end tell

to checkForFolder({parentFolder:fParent, folderName:fName})
    --find or create a folder
    tell application "System Events"
        --set fName to POSIX file of fName as alias
        --set fParent to POSIX file of fParent as alias

        if not (exists POSIX path of (folder fName of folder fParent)) then
            set output to POSIX path of (make new folder at end of folder fParent with properties {name:fName})
        else
            set output to (POSIX path of (folder fName of folder fParent))
        end if
    end tell

    --returns a POSIX path
    return output
end checkForFolder
```

After hours of poring over the Apple Forums, Stack Overflow and consulting the Google oracle, I'm aware that context matters, so I'm trying to provide as much information as possible. Here, I've printed (log) the contents and Class types of thisFile, targetFolder and finalTarget1:

(*targetFolder: /Volumes/Public2/Pictures/LINP/temp/2013-06-04*)

(*targetFolder Class: text*)

thisFile

(*file Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg*)

(*thisFile Class: file*)

(*finalTarget1: Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:2013-06-04:*)

(*finalTarget1 Class: text*)

And here are the errors displayed by each of the two move attempts:

move thisFile to the folder finalTarget1

= move file "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg" to folder "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:2013-06-04:"

error "System Events got an error: Can’t get file \"Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg\". " number -1728 from file "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg"

move thisFile to the folder targetFolder

= move file "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg" to folder "/Volumes/Public2/Pictures/LINP/temp/2013-06-04"

error "System Events got an error: Can’t get file \"Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg\". " number -1728 from file "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg"

Finally, yes, Public2 is mounted and I know that it's accessible since I'm getting the full folder contents back AND creating each of the sub-folders appropriately. It's just this last "move" operation that is failing and I'm sure it's a product of my ignorance.

Can anyone help identify the cause and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I took your script and quickly made a local version to test, with two jpegs in the temp folder. So far, this is what I came across.
Fix #1:

```
move thisFile to the folder finalTarget1
```

needs to be changed to

```
move thisFile to finalTarget1
```

but then there's is an error with

```
move thisFile to the folder targetFolder
```

because the script is attempting to move the file it already moved. Not sure if that line is in there for testing purposes. Maybe you can clarify. If I comment out the 2nd line it seems to work.

Comment: CRGreen: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, when I change that line to "move thisFile to finalTarget1," it errors with:

move file "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:000DC5D1A54E(Patio)_1_20130604084734_139988.jpg" to "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:2013-06-04:"--> error number -1700 from "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:2013-06-04:" to location specifier
Result:
error "System Events got an error: Can’t make \"Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:2013-06-04:\" into type location specifier." number -1700 from "Public2:Pictures:LINP:temp:2013-06-04:" to location specifier

Comment: As for the two moves, I was trying two slightly different moves to see if one would work. I provided the output of each attempt in my post in the hopes that the resulting error messages would be helpful in determining the problem.

Comment: Hi @user3171341. I'm not seeing that error. When I run the script with the first line modified to "move thisFile to finalTarget1", it works. What version OS are you using? Keep the 2nd line commented out, but see if one this works for the 1st move line: `move thisFile to (my finalTarget1 as alias)` If this works I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Also (I know this seems weird), try this one: `move alias (thisFile as alias as text) to (finalTarget1 as alias)`